# MultiValueDictKeyError at /users/signup/ "password_1"

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am learning django, And while creating the user. I got this error MultiValueDictKeyError at /users/signup/ "password_1", Please help me

views.py, The last defined function, at passwords1. This is the place where it is pointing the error.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your views here.


def userslogin(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "users/login.html", {
                "message": "Invalid credentials."
            })
    else:
        return render(request, "users/login.html")

def userlogout(request):
    logout(request)
    return render(request, 'users/logout.html',{
                "message": "Succesfully logged out."
})

def usersignup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        email = request.POST["email"]
        password_1 = request.POST["password_1"]
        password_2 = request.POST["password_2"]
        myuser = User.objects.create_superuser(username = username,password = password_1, email=email)
        if myuser is not None:            
            myuser.save() 
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("main"))
        else:
            return render(request, "users/login.html", {
                "message": "Invalid credentials."
            })
        
        
    else:
         
        return render(request, "users/signup.html")
```

urls.py Nothings is wrong here, But still, I have included this file

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
import blog


urlpatterns = [
    path("", blog.views.main, name="index"),
    path('login/',views.userslogin, name = 'login'),
    path('logout/',views.userlogout, name = 'logout'),
    path('signup/',views.usersignup, name = 'signup'),
    
]
```

signup.html

```
{% extends 'users/layout.html' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Physics Blog</h1>

    {% if message %}
        <div>{{ message }}</div>
    {% endif %}
    
    <form  action= "{% url 'signup' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" placeholder="username" name = "username" id="username">
        <input type="email" placeholder="email" name = "email" id="email">
        <input type="password" placeholder="password 1">
        <input type="password" placeholder="password 2">
        <input type="submit">

    </form>
    

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the **name** of the `input` widget so that the `request.POST[]` can capture the value by **`input`** widget name. Add `name=password_1, name=password_2` in your input widget

```
<form action="{% url 'signup' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" name = "username" id="username">
    <input type="email" placeholder="email" name = "email" id="email">
    <input type="password" name="password_1" placeholder="password 1">
    <input type="password" name="password_2" placeholder="password 2">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```